# MultiMonitor setup with Mini HDMI

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have an ultrabook, with a mini HDMI port. I have a desktop monitor which has VGA. Is there any way I can connect these two to create a multi-monitor setup?

Comment: You should get a Mini HDMI to VGA converter

Comment: Will that work? Some say that it will only duplicate the screen.

Comment: I doubt it, but you never know... what is the model and brand of your ultrabook?

Comment: Actually thats the catch, my Ultrabook is a prototype that I won in a contest. If it helps heres the ultrabook http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InitialImpressionsOfThe3rdGenerationIvyBridgeIntelUltrabookReferenceHardwareForDevelopersOnWindows8.aspx

Comment: It will work as a dual-monitor setup. Use the Win+P combination to choose 'extend' and you'll be fine.

Comment: ok, will try and respond